# CollectD Java plugin incorrectly showing zero in Graphite

Tags: java, graphite, collectd

[CollectD](https://collectd.org/) is all about plugins.

One plugin is the Java plugin.  Documented [here](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Java), [here](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd.conf.5.shtml#plugin_java) and [here](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-java.5.shtml).  The function of the Java plugin is to host other plugins.

One such Java plugin is [GenericJMX](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX) whose source code is [here](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/tree/master/bindings/java/org/collectd/java).  Using that class and another simpler one, JMXMemory2.java, I've created a class which statically reports a value over and over and over.  It does so over the different collectD data types which are somewhat explained [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/types.db).

**The problem I am having is that when displayed in Graphite, only 1 data type reports the actual value.  The rest display zero.**  If I create and use a custom datatype, the data is graphed as expected.  I would like to use the builtin generic types of absolute, counter, derive and gauge.  This so that I do not have to create new datatypes in types.db.

The value is set every time to the number 12.

absolute                value:ABSOLUTE:0:U

------> graphs what looks like a heartbeat, centered on 1.2

counter                 value:COUNTER:U:U

------> graphs 0

derive                  value:DERIVE:0:U

------> graphs 0

gauge                   value:GAUGE:U:U

------> graphs 0

memory                  value:GAUGE:0:281474976710656

------> graphs a straight line of 12

memory2                value:GAUGE:0:281474976710656

------> graphs a straight line of 12

Answer (score 0):

May be I get something wrong, but according to [collectd wiki](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Data_source) only GAUGE type shows the actual value.

> The value is set every time to the number 12

If you specified DERIVE type, you'll see how the metric changing over time, which means, if you always have `value = 12` you'd always get `0` with DERIVE type, right?